# What happens to photopolymer chemically when it is cured by uv light?

Tags: polymers

I'm writing an essay on how 3d printing process effects the structure of the material used and im finding it hard to find what actually happens to the polymer when it is cured. I know that it is made up of monomers, oligomers and photoinitiators and other information would be much appreciated.

Comment: Search for Radical Polymerisation. The Wikipedia article has an example of a photochemically initiated reaction.

Answer (score 2):

Curing is simply crosslinking between polymer chains. In the first days of rubber, sulfur was used to crosslink the natural double bonds in the rubber (known as vulcanisation).
Similarly,  in the case of your question, UV light will cause a photoxidation or other photoinitiation process to bond the relevantly, reactive atoms in the chain to others in another polymer chain. The extent of cross-linking will determine if you obtain an elastomer ~1% crosslinking) or a thermoset polymer (definitely >2% crosslinking).